# Comparing null and number in groovy

Tags: groovy

Why is the following true in Groovy?

```
0 > null
```

Is it by choice or is it just a consequence of the implementation of compareTo?

I'm using Groovy 2.0.5.

Comment: If NULL is 0, then it would be false, right?

Comment: I was unclear... Mr. tim_yates answered

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Groovy `null` is the lowest possible element, so everything is `> null`

```
assert                    'tim' > null
assert                        0 > null
assert                       -1 > null
assert Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY > null
```

This means things like this can work:

```
[ 1, null, 3 ].sort()
```

Otherwise what would happen?  If you want this to work, you have to say *"null is lower than anything"* or *"null is higher than anything"*...

Groovy chose the former

Comment: was not better if null always give false? null<0==false null>0==false null==0==false ?

Comment: @Fabiano: Tim already covered that in his answer. using 'always false' won't give you consistent sorting.