# How to compare for null in groovy correctly?

Tags: groovy, null, comparison

edit: Stupid. The problem was that I got a string with value 'null'

---

How to compare for null in groovy correctly?

I've got the following script

```
println "row6: " + row[6]

if(row[6] == null) {
  println "if"
}
  else {
  println "else"
}
```

When I run it with a row where the specified field is null this is the output:

```
row6: null
else
```

The [Groovy Docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java) say `a == null` will work, while `a.is(null)` will not.

So how do I compare for null in groovy the right way?

P.S. I saw [The SO-Thread: comparing-null-and-number-in-groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532582/comparing-null-and-number-in-groovy). It says that null is handled as a number, but this would still mean a `==` comparision should work when the value is null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code prints *if*:

```
def row = []
row[6] = null
println "row6: " + row[6]

if(row[6] == null) {
  println "if"
} else {
  println "else"
}
```

Are you sure that `row[6]` is null?

Comment: yes. see the debug line `println "row6: " + row[6]` which results in `row6: null`. Also in my script when the script enters the else-part it crashs cause of Null Pointer Exception when trying to convert the null to int: `Data conversion error converting "'null' (yyy: xxx INT)"`

Comment: Provide the full example.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints the output from the question:

```
def row = []
row[6] = "null"
println "row6: " + row[6]

if(row[6] == null) {
  println "if"
} else {
  println "else"
}
```

So it should be evident that row[6] is not null but a string containing "null".